# Python 3.7 input() doesnt work but raw_input does

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, visual-studio-code

So classic beginner problem here... Ive been trying to use Python on various text editors like VSCode and Atom and none of them seem to work (After installing python 3.7). If I ask for a simple input the program crashes labelling the input as undefined, but when I use raw_input() it works just fine for some reason. However, raw_input() was changed to input() in Python 3 so why does this keep happening to me?

Comment: Post your code and error

Comment: What do you mean by "*crashes labelling the input as undefined*"?

Comment: Because you aren't using Python 3.7, but Python 2.  If you can `print` instead of `print()` it's Python 2.  Or check `sys.version`.  You've likely got multiple versions installed and your IDE is using a different one than you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using virtual environments. Since you're running on a Mac I would suggest you use the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos) distribution of Python. Instructions are [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html). This simplifies the process of making virtual environments. It's as easy as `conda create -n myenv python=3.6` and more detailed instructions are found [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). Once conda is installed you can use commands like `conda install scipy`to install python packages. Once you have virtual environments installed and activated your command should work. Try it in the python 3.6 environment.

Comment: After following this set of instructions would python 3.6+ automatically work in VSCode?

Comment: Should with no problem. VScode actually lets you chose which version of interpeter to use.

Answer (score 1):

Strange,

I guess something wrong with installation,

Please check what:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Outputs,

and also see what this outputs:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

And see if this works:

```
print 'hello'
```

If it does work, you're on python 2, also see what `sys.version` and `platform.python_version()` outputs

Comment: Yeah despite installing python from the main page of their website, it says I'm on Python version 2.7.10, How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

As U9-Forward has mentioned in his answer, similarly...

> Check that the installtion of Python 3.7 is correct by entering the follwoing into the Python 3.7 native IDLE Shell (you may have been using the IDLE of an older Python version):
>   `import sys`
>   `print(sys.version)`
> and...
> `import platform`
> `print(platform.python_version())`
> If any of this produces an error, you will know if there was a problem with installation.

It's possible that you have multiple versions of Python installed. Check to see what versions you do have installed. If you have other versions besides Python 3.7 uninstall them. 
If the problem persists uninstall Python 3.7 and reinstall it.

The problem as you described can occur when one attempt to install a newer version of Python when older version(s) are still installed.

Comment: You're right I installed 3.7 multiple times to fix the problem and nothing worked. How would I go about uninstalling it on MacOSX though?

Comment: Take a look at https://osxuninstaller.com/uninstall-guides/properly-uninstall-python-mac/  Note this is a guide for Python 3.6 so you may need to adjust for that.

Comment: If you have found my advice helpful please upvote my answer and mark as the accepted answer. Thankyou

Comment: Are you running on a Mac or PC? Unix/Linux or Windows?

Comment: Im running Latest OSX on Mac. None of the guides provided have helped me uninstall Python 2.7, only 3.7 so im still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Sames happends to me, i uninstall all anaconda + spyder. then i install 3.7. 
-variable-input(), works on 3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6 nd 3.7.
on all other -variable-raw_input workds

**dsclmer: -variable- replace with your own variable such as name or age etc, eg..**