# OSX Python 2 binary interfering with python 3

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to program in python 3, but visual code keeps defaulting me to python 2. I have my interpreter set to python 3, but input() does not work, only raw_input works instead. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: My question is similar to this, [Python 3.7 input() doesnt work but raw_input does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471860/python-3-7-input-doesnt-work-but-raw-input-does) but none of the answers managed to solve my problem.

Comment: Python 3 does not come pre-installed on OSX (as far as I remember). Just making sure you have it installed.
Do you execute your script using `$ python3 myscript.py`?

Comment: @Sazzy Sorry. I meant the python 2.7.10 being pre-installed on OSX (in usr/bin/python) is being defaulted on visual code, even though 3x is being used as the interpreter. I use code runner to execute the script via code.

Comment: Try adding this to the top of your python file:
`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OSX I liked used Virtualenv to resolve problem with Python2 and Python3

```
[sudo] pip install virtualenv
```

After installation:

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

## RUN

```
source my_project/bin/activate
```

## deactivate

```
deactivate
```

Comment: Thanks! This managed to do it. I also needed to edit code-runner.Executormap to get it working.